# ¿Cómo ejecutar una aplicación desarrollada con Node.js y Express con vistas Jade para visualizarla en cualquier equipo?

Tags: jquery, mysql, nodejs, express, sequelize.js

Chicos alguien sabe como puedo visualizar o entrar a la aplicación que hice en otros equipos además del mío, sin que estén conectados a mi misma red, el sistema maneja Express, Node.js, sequelize, las vistas las hice con jade. La base de datos en mysql y la ejecuto con xampp

Aquí una imagen[image: Repositorio de mi app]

La ejecuto con unarchivo .bat que contiene las siguientes instrucciones

set DEBUG=myapp:* & npm start

[image: start.bat]

Y visualizo mi app con localhost:3000
[image: SISTEMA LOGIN]

Comment: Si no estás conectado directamente a internet (es de suponer que hay un router entre medio) tendrías que hacer que el puerto 80 de tu router redirija al 3000 de tu equipo local (averiguando la IP interna que el router le da a tu equipo). Generalmente los routers ofrecen una opción de port forwarding

Comment: "sin que estén conectados a mi misma red" -> si no están ni conectados a Internet, imposible.

Answer (score 0):

¿Desde tu mismo PC?
Lo ideal es contratar un hosting que admita nodejs y mysql para montar el entorno que tienes actualmente en tu PC, en la nube.

Si quieres que sea desde tu mismo PC, debes abrir los puertos de tu router (no lo recomiento por la seguridad) y podrías con tu ip pública acceder desde otro pc a tu aplicación (eso sí, teniendo lanzado el servidor node y xampp).

Espero te haya servido.

Answer (score 0):

Realmente hay varias cosas por revisar, ya que, npm puede levantar su aplicación en modo desarrollo o producción, aquí lo primero es definir en que modo desea desplegar su aplicación para que sea accesada, ya que, en modo desarrollo la consola del navegador estará dando información que no conviene mostrar si la aplicación se sirve para producción. Para que revises esto recomiendo [esta enlace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/deployment)

Si la aplicación es de uso exclusivo de una intranet, sería prudente que ésta se sirva desde una PC dedicada, qué significa? No utilizar la misma PC con la que desarrolla o utiliza para tener la app arriba.

Personalmente recomiendo lo siguiente, existen sitio como [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) o [Linode](https://www.linode.com/) por $5 mensuales usted no necesita más que instalar y configurar el OS, con esto se evita todo el problema de modem, router, puertos, antivirus (en su caso). Debe valorar costo/beneficio, ya que de primera entrada pareciera mas rentable tenerlo localmente pero debe hacer una revisión cuidadosa de las implicaciones y los escenarios que se puedan dar